# Preserve file names in dev mode

Tags: vite

In development mode with Vite, the CSS styles are typically injected into the HTML file using a  tag, and the file names of the imported CSS files are not preserved. Is there a way to preserve the file names and line? (same as webpack example)

In webpack you have the file name and the line of the style applied:

[image: webpack example]

In vite you have <style> instead of name:line:

[image: vite exaple]

Answer (score 2):

After hours of research I find out that you can reach same result as webpack setting [css.devSourcemap](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-devsourcemap) to true in your vite.config.js.

e.g.

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
  // all your config
  css: {
    devSourcemap: true,
  },
});
```